# Copy-PasteSpecial fails on large ranges

Tags: excel, vba

Pastespecial to paste values from a column into the next column but having difficulties getting it to work.

If I use this code it works fine

```
Sub cps()
Range("F2:F500").Copy
Range("G2:G500").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Snag is it's an Excel sheet looking at SQL so the number of rows changes, today there are 2100 and tomorrow there might be 2110. So I tried the below to make sure I caught all the rows..

```
Sub cps()
Range("F2:F5000").Copy
Range("G2:G5000").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' <~~~~ Error
End Sub
```

But I get an error on the line `Range("G2:G5000").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`

How do I do this if I don't know how many rows there are in the sheet?

So Thomas gave me a solution which works but I just need to adapt the code to look at 3 separate sheets, AP, EMEA and WH.

Comment: I tested your code and couldn't reproduce your issue. The code worked as expected. Can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: When pointing to the paste range, only specify the top-left cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. Maybe it bugs because you are not running it from the sheetmodule and you didn't qualified your Range. For instance : ***Sheets("Sheet1")***.Range or ***ActiveSheet***.Range like I do below. Also this code will only copy the used range like you asked.

**Edit: *Adding stuff to call it from any sheet***

Create a new module and move this Sub in it :

```
Public Sub CopyCOlumnF(strSheet As String)

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Sheets(strSheet)
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row ' Column "F"=6
        .Range("F1:F" & LastRow).Copy
        .Range("G1:G" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

End Sub
```

Then in any of your sheetmodules, call the sub like this:

```
Sub cps()
    CopyCOlumnF (ActiveSheet.Name)
End Sub
```

You can also call it from any place and apply the trick to any sheet like this:

```
CopyCOlumnF ("Sheet1")
CopyCOlumnF ("Sheet2")
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks Thomas. One question though I have 3 sheets and want to run this macro against all 3, how would I do that? Sheets are called AP, EMEA and WH

Comment: Edit your initial question while I am editing the initial answer